# parse natural language

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, regex

**To start:**  I know this system will have flaws!

**NOTE:** Im adding a few other languages because I don't find this problem specific to php..A JavaScript or jquery solution would work...I could change the language ...Its the method i am after!

**What:** I am trying to parse a string to determine what the user desires.

*The idea is that the string is generated from voice*

*Example 1:*
Turn my kitchen lights on and my bedroom and living room lights off.

*Example 2:*
Turn my kitchen lights on and my bedroom lights on and living room lights off.

*Example 3:*
Turn my kitchen and my bedroom and living room lights off.

This is an overly simplified example but please note that I want to scale beyond these three room as well as just controlling the lights
example: outside ceiling fan on...

**How:** I am currently using a few while loops to iterate through an array and the checking if certain strings are in the array.

**More how:** My idea was to first split on the string on the "and". I then check each array for a on or off. If it does not have a on or off i join the array with the next.

**Help:** I would love to clean this concept up as well as see someone else s ideas...I am up for anything ..

Thanks
JT

**CODE:**

```
$input = 'kitchen lights on and bed and living lights off'; 
$output = preg_split( "/ (and) /", $input );
$num = (int)count($output);
$i=0;

while($i<$num){
    if ((strpos($output[$i],'on') !== false)||(strpos($output[$i],'off') !== false)) {}
    elseif(((strpos($output[$i+1],'on') !== false)||(strpos($output[$i+1],'off') !== false))){
    $output[$i+1] .= ' + '.$output[$i];
        unset($output[$i]);

    }

    $i++;
}
$output = array_values($output);
$i=0;
$num = (int)count($output);
echo '<br>';
while($i<$num){
if ((strpos($output[$i],'lights') !== false)&&(strpos($output[$i],'on') !== false)&&(strpos($output[$i],'kitchen') !== false)){
echo'kitchen lights on<br>';
}
if ((strpos($output[$i],'lights') !== false)&&(strpos($output[$i],'off') !== false)&&(strpos($output[$i],'kitchen') !== false)){
echo'kitchen lights off<br>';
}
if ((strpos($output[$i],'lights') !== false)&&(strpos($output[$i],'on') !== false)&&(strpos($output[$i],'living') !== false)){
echo'living lights on<br>';
}
if ((strpos($output[$i],'lights') !== false)&&(strpos($output[$i],'off') !== false)&&(strpos($output[$i],'living') !== false)){
echo'living lights off<br>';
}
if ((strpos($output[$i],'lights') !== false)&&(strpos($output[$i],'on') !== false)&&(strpos($output[$i],'bed') !== false)){
echo'bed lights on<br>';
}
if ((strpos($output[$i],'lights') !== false)&&(strpos($output[$i],'off') !== false)&&(strpos($output[$i],'bed') !== false)){
echo'bed lights off<br>';
}   
$i++;
}
```

**Code trial 2:** Note: This handles all the above examples!

```
<?php
//works list
$inp[]='turn the lights in the bedroom on';
$inp[]='Turn on the bedroom light';
$inp[]='turn on the lights in the bedroom';
$inp[]='Turn my kitchen and my bedroom and living room lights off.';
$inp[]='Turn the light in the kitchen on and the fan in the bedroom off';
$inp[]='Turn my kitchen lights on and my bedroom and living room lights off';
$inp[]='Turn my kitchen fan and my bedroom lights on and living room lights off.';
$inp[]='Turn my kitchen lights on and my bedroom lights on and living room lights off';
$inp[] = 'kitchen lights on and bath and living lights off'; 
$inp[] = 'flip on the lights in the living room';
$inp[] = 'turn on all lights';

//does not work list
//$inp[] = 'turn on all lights but living';

foreach ($inp as $input){

$input = trim($input);
$input  = rtrim($input, '.');
$input = trim($input);
$input  = rtrim($input, '.');


$words = explode(" ", $input);

$state = array('and','but','on','off','all','living','bed','bedroom','bath','kitchen','dining','light','lights','fan','tv');
$result = array_intersect($words, $state);
$result = implode(" ", $result);
$result = trim($result);
    //$result = preg_split('/(and|but)/',$input,-1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
$result = preg_split( "/ (and|but) /",  $result );
    //$result = explode("and", $result);

$sep=array();

foreach($result as $string){
$word = explode(" ", $string);
$sep[]=$word;   
}

$test=array();
$num = (int)count($sep);

$i=0;

while($i<($num)){   
$result = (int)count(array_intersect($sep[$i], $state));    
$j=$i;

    while($result<=3)
    {
        $imp = implode(" ", $sep[$j]);
        if(isset($test[$i])){$test[$i]=$imp.' '.$test[$i];}
        else{$test[$i]=$imp;}

        if ($result>=3){$j++;break;}        
        $result = (int)count(array_intersect($sep[++$j], $state));      
    }
$i=$j;
}

print_r($test);
    echo '<br>';
}


?>
```

Comment: @ILA_JT me too... It's a fun exercise I think!

Comment: I wouldn't look for `and`, but just a list of predifined target keywords `kitchen`, `living room`, `bedroom` and the nearest `on`/`off`. Which a simple regex and `preg_match_all()` would cover.

Comment: @mario could you define nearest...characters?... Im not sure of how a reg ex could handle all three examples but id love to see a example!

Comment: I would simplify that even further with `preg_split('/(on|off)/', $input, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE)`. You get the state in [2*n+1] and find the room keywords in [2*n+0]` in the resulting array using `preg_match_all('/(kitchen|living|bedroom|garage/'`.

Comment: @mario ok u lost me at the 2*n+1 part... Why not put this as an answer...just a thought :P

Comment: It is much faster to do something like this with radio buttons, because the user doesn't have to 'think'. I get that this is an exercise, but a more practical example would make more sense.

Comment: @remyabel this is not the point of this...The idea is that the string is generated from voice.

Comment: @tman That wasn't mentioned anywhere in the question or in the comments.

Comment: @remyabel the title :) kind of :p

Comment: @tman 'Natural language' doesn't necessarily imply voice input, especially if you're parsing it.

Comment: @remyabel how its generated didn't serve as relevance in my mind... but i did add the edit. Sorry about that!

Comment: @mario how would the 2*n+1 grab the correct results ... i missing the pattern your seeing!

Comment: @tman It's still a rather obtuse way to approach it. I'm expecting that the way you're generating the string will in itself produce you the data you want.

Comment: @remyabel in itself produce you the data you want? Please by all means show me a easier way to get the data!

Comment: @tman Yes, metadata. Rather than parsing the string generated from the input, why not just parse the input?

Comment: @remyabel this is the input....voice->voicetranslation->string

Answer (score 3):

Parsing natural language is non-trivial, if you want a true natural language parser I'd recommend that you try and use an existing project or library. Here's a [web based parser](http://naturalparsing.com/browserparser/parse), based on the [Stanford Parser](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/lex-parser.shtml). Or [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing) is a good jumping off point.

Having said that, if you're willing to restrict the syntax and the keywords involved you might be able to simplify it. First you need to know what's important -- you have 'things' (lights, fan) in 'places' (bedroom, kitchen) that need to go into a specific state ('on', 'off').

I would get the string into an array of words, either using [str_tok](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtok.php), or just explode on `' '`.

Now you have an array of words start at the *end* and go backwards looking for a 'state' -- on or off. Then follow that backwards looking for a 'thing', and finally a 'place'. If you hit another state then you can start again.

Let me try and do that in pseudocode:

```
// array of words is inArray
currentPlace = null;
currentThing = null; 
currentState = null;
for (i = (inArray.length - 1); i >= 0; i--) {
    word = inArray[i];

    if (isState(word)) {

      currentState = word;
      currentPlace = null;
      currentThing = null;

    } else if (currentState) {

        if (isThing(word)) { 

             currentThing = word;
             currentPlace = null;

        } else if (currentThing) { 

             if (isPlace(word)) { 
                 currentPlace = word
                 // Apply currentState to currentThing in currentPlace
             }
             // skip non-place, thing or state word. 
        }
        // Skip when we don't have a thing to go with our state

    } 
    // Skip when we don't have a current state and we haven't found a state
}
```

And, having written that, it's pretty clear that it should have used a state machine and switch statements -- which goes to show I should have designed it on paper first. If you get anymore complex you want to use a state machine to implement the logic -- states would be 'lookingForState', 'lookingForThing', etc

Also you don't really need `currentPlace` as a variable, but I'll leave it as it makes the logic clearer.

**EDIT**

If you want to support 'turn the lights in the bedroom on' you'll need to be adjust the logic (you need to save the 'place' if when you don't have a thing). If you also want to support 'turn on the lights in the bedroom' you'll need to go even further.

Thinking about it, I wonder if you can just do:

```
have a currentState variable and arrays for currentPlace and currentThing
for each word 
    if it's a state:
        store it in currentState 
    if it's a thing, or place:
        add it to the approriate array
        if currentState is set and there is content in currentPlaces and currentThings:
            apply currentState to all currentThings in all currentPlaces
```

That's not quite there, but one of those implementations might give you a starting point.

**EDIT 2**

OK, I tested it out and there's a few issues due to the way English is structured. The problem is if you want to support 'Turn on ...' and 'Turn ... on' then you need to use my second pseudo-code but that doesn't work easily because of the 'and's in the sentence. For example:

Turn my kitchen lights on *and* my bedroom **and** living room lights off.

The first and joins two statements, the second and joins to places. The correct way to do this is to [diagram the sentence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentence_diagram) to work out what applies to what.

There are two quick options, first you could insist on using a different word or phrase to join two commands:

Turn my kitchen lights on *then* my bedroom **and** living room lights off.
  Turn my kitchen lights on *and also* my bedroom **and** living room lights off.

Alternatively, and this is probably easier you can insist on only having commands of the form 'Turn ... off/on'. This works with my first psuedocode above.

[JavaScript Example](http://jsfiddle.net/SpaceDog/hyhua/2/) of first psuedocode.

Note, you'll probably need to heavily pre-process the string if there's any chance of punctuation, etc. You might also want to look at replacing 'living room' (and similar two word phrases) with 'livingroom' rather than just matching one word and hoping for the best like I'm doing. Also, the code could be simplified a bit, but I wanted to keep it close to the psuedocode example.

**EDIT 3**

[New Javascript Example](http://jsfiddle.net/SpaceDog/pGJSY/1/)

This handles some extra sentences and is cleaned up a bit better, it still relies on the 'state' coming at the end of each clause as that's what it uses as a trigger to apply the actions (this version could probably read forwards instead of backwards). Also, it will not handle something like:

```
Turn my kitchen fan and my bedroom lights on and living room lights off.
```

You have to do something more complex to understand the relationship between 'kitchen' and 'fan' and 'bedroom' and 'lights'.

Some combination of those techniques is probably enough to do something fairly impressive, as long as whoever's entering / speaking the commands follows some basic rules.

Comment: reading now... sorry for the delay... wow I like your approach. ahh the logic of getting even decent results still seems hairy to me though. I think you highlighted it well when you gave the multiple examples of what can be said

Comment: I really want to say I fully understand your approach but its still getting to me. Ok so Ill do my best to summarize and you tell me where im off. We have Place, Thing, and State. We blow up the string into individual words. Run through the array from the end foreward looking for a Place, Thing, or State. Once we find one we then keep going looking for Place, Thing, or State scratching off what we had just found. This is where i get a little confused ... what now... I WOULD LOVE A SEMI WORKING EXAMPLE...can i entice you with some rep points lol...Thanks for your input

Comment: Let me think on it some more and see if I can knock together a concrete example, can't promise anything quickly but I'll see what I can do.

Comment: OK, it was a good puzzle to solve, I've added a concrete example -- it'll not work for all English sentences as I describe, but it will work for your examples and it should be extendable. Should be easy to port to any other language.

Comment: ahh Thanks for your time sir...im going to spend some time picking through this ...Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your edit...im still trying to dive into those that you said wont work. Ill post back when/if I get somewhere

Comment: I created a much more compact version of my original example code. As of now it seems to handle everything except some difficult ones like. Please turn off all my lights but my kitchen...If you want I could share ...Though its in php...Id love some input on how to handle some of the extremes

Comment: I assume that's the second code you've added, I'm quite impressed that it's got this far using that method. Handling the extremes might get quite tricky. I'll have a look at your code and see if I have any ideas.

Comment: I am a bit surprised to... It brought me to a new way of thinking about it though. I wonder if i could run the string through google or something and try to find out what the statement desires. Im curious if google and siri do something more bassed on the response from there database or if they do anything like what we tried...For example siri what is the weather outside today...or whats the temperature outside...anyways thanks for the interest in my problem i enjoy discussing it

Answer (score 3):

That's certainly not the most efficient solution, but here's one. You can definitely improve it, like caching regular expressions, but you get the idea. The last item in every sub-array is the operation.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/PQBhk/2/)**

```
var s = 'Turn my kitchen lights on and my bedroom lights on and living room lights off and my test and another test off',
    r = s.replace(/^Turn|\s*my/g, '').match(/.+? (on|off)/g).map(function(item) {
        var items = item.trim().replace(/^and\s*/, '').split(/\s*and\s*/),
            last = items.pop().split(' '),
            op = last.pop();
        return items.concat([last.join(' '), op]);
    });

console.log(r);
```

> Mind explaining the logic u used... I mean im reading the code but i
>   was just curious if you could say it better

The logic is quite simple actually, perhaps too simple:

```
var s = 'Turn my kitchen lights on and my bedroom lights on and living room lights off and my test and another test off',
    r = s
        .replace(/^Turn|\s*my/g, '') //remove noisy words
        .match(/.+? (on|off)/g) //capture all groups of [some things][on|off]
        //for each of those groups, generate a new array from the returned results
        .map(function(item) {
            var items = item.trim()
                    .replace(/^and\s*/, '') //remove and[space] at the beginning of string
                    //split on and to get all things, for instance if we have
                    //test and another test off, we want ['test', 'another test off']
                    .split(/\s*and\s*/),
                //split the last item on spaces, with previous example we would get
                //['another', 'test', 'off']
                last = items.pop().split(' '),
                op = last.pop(); //on/off will always be the last item in the array, pop it
            //items now contains ['test'], concatenate with the array passed as argument
            return items.concat(
                [
                    //last is ['another', 'test'], rejoin it together to give 'another test'
                    last.join(' '),
                    op //this is the operation
                ]
            );
        });
```

EDIT: At the time I posted the answer, **I haven't realized how complex and flexible you needed this to be. The solution I provided would only work for sentences structured as in my example, with identifiable noisy words and a specific command order.** For something more complex, you will have no other choice but to create a parser like @SpaceDog suggested. I will try to come up with something as soon as I have enough time.

Comment: Ahh i like this... Mind explaining the logic u used... I mean im reading the code but i was just curious if you could say it better lol

Comment: I created a much more compact version of my original example code. As of now it seems to handle everything except some difficult ones like. Please turn off all my lights but my kitchen...If you want I could share ...Though its in php.. Id love some input on how to handle that.

Comment: @tman, I'm glad that you found a solution. It would be a good idea to post an answer and accept your own ;) I think once you have a flexible parser setup, it wouldn't be too hard to handle these.

Answer (score 1):

I have been working on [parsing menus and recipes](http://www.noclu.com/ingredients) (not finished) and this is my approach:

- find the sentences separators (I use AND as well as others)
- parse each sentence to find the `key` words that you need (light/bulbs/etc.., on/off)
- if you have a limited set of places (kitchen, bathroom, etc...)

  - search for those keywords, remove the others
  - ELSE
  - remove the `extra words` that some people might use (bright, colorful, etc...)
- store it into an array, something that might look like this:

  - what
  - where
- if you do not have one of the fields, leave it blank
- for each result check what you have and if you have a blank field fill it up with the previous parsing

I.E.: Turn the lights on in the bedroom and in the kitchen

- 1:

  - turn the light on in the bedroom
  - what: lights on
  - where: bedroom
- 2:

  - in the kitchen
  - what:
  - where: kitchen

`what_2` is empty, then `what_2` is `lights on`

keep in mind that sometime needs to fill up the array with the next results (depending on how the sentence is structured, but it is rare), I add a "+" or "-" to it so I know if I have to go forward or backwards to find the missing parts while parsing it